# Why isn't the last known position of a black box continuously available?

Tags: safety, air-traffic-control, flight-data-recorder

I have read that some GPS satellites receive this data. Where is that information recorded? Why would it not be used? Inmarsat covers all but the polar regions, why don't the airlines use that system to transmit and track aircraft location data? I don't think that cost would exclude this, as a crash is hugely expensive, especially counting downstream costs (search and recovery, collateral damage, etc.).http://www.inmarsat.com/about-us/our-satellites/our-coverage/

Comment: GPS satellites do not receive data.  They only transmit.

Comment: This is a much-too-broad question. The FDR/CVR's purpose and their technology are completely different than the Inmarsat which itself is completely different than GPS. None of them, in their current designs and purposes are for real-time communications (reporting) of the location of something TO someone else.

Comment: This question is set to be closed by giving one example as duplicate that is closed...